# How do I push the array object into another?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

I want to match id and parentId and get the new object

element can take more than one data and must be nested according to id matching

I couldn't find how to match and can I search the new list after converting?

is it possible to do such a dynamic function?

I will use this code in an angular project

First Array

```
[
  {
    id: '1',
    parentId: 0,
    name: 'x'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    parentId: 1,
    name: 'y'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    parentId: 2,
    name: 'z'
  },
  {
    id: '4',
    parentId: 2,
    name: 'q'
  },
  {
    id: '5',
    parentId: 3,
    name: 'e'
  },
  {
    id: '6',
    parentId: 5,
    name: 'r'
  }
]
```

new object

```
{
  element: [
    {
      data: {
        id: '1',
        parentId: 0,
        name: 'x'
      },
      element: [
        {
          data: {
            id: '2',
            parentId: 1,
            name: 'y'
          },
          element: [
            {
              data: {
                id: '3',
                parentId: 2,
                name: 'z'
              },
              element: [
                {
                  data: {
                    id: '5',
                    parentId: 3,
                    name: 'e'
                  },
                  element: [
                    {
                      data: {
                        id: '6',
                        parentId: 5,
                        name: 'r'
                      },
                      element: [

                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              data: {
                id: '4',
                parentId: 2,
                name: 'q'
              },
              element: [

              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think this is what you want.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19222113/reorder-a-js-object-in-a-child-parent-structure

Comment: you can use lodash to achieve this. Sorry for bad formatting. The question was closed. Couldn't post as an answer



`function transformToTree(arr){
    var nodes = {};    
    return arr.filter(function(obj){
        var id = obj["id"],
            parentId = obj["parentId"];

        nodes[id] = _.defaults(obj, nodes[id], { element: [] });
        parentId && (nodes[parentId] = (nodes[parentId] || { element: [] }))["element"].push(obj);

        return !parentId;
    });    
}`

Answer (score 1):

In the [MSN Javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) look up `Array.find()`.  Basically, pass a simple expression for the search.